# Counting all co-occurrences of a large list of nouns and verbs/adjectives within reviews

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a dataframe that contains a large number of reviews, a large list with noun words (1000) and another large list with verbs/adjectives (1000).

Example dataframe and lists:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'reviews':['Very professional operation. Room is very clean and comfortable',
                    'Daniel is the most amazing host! His place is extremely clean, and he provides everything you could possibly want (comfy bed, guidebooks & maps, mini-fridge, towels, even toiletries). He is extremely friendly and helpful.',
                    'The room is very quiet, and well decorated, very clean.',
                    'He provides the room with towels, tea, coffee and a wardrobe.',
                    'Daniel is a great host. Always recomendable.',
                    'My friend and I were very satisfied with our stay in his apartment.']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

nouns = ['place','Amsterdam','apartment','location','host','stay','city','room','everything','time','house',
         'area','home','’','center','restaurants','centre','Great','tram','très','minutes','walk','space','neighborhood',
         'à','station','bed','experience','hosts','Thank','bien']

verbs_adj = ['was','is','great','nice','had','clean','were','recommend','stay','are','good','perfect','comfortable',
             'have','easy','be','quiet','helpful','get','beautiful',"'s",'has','est','located','un','amazing','wonderful',]
```

I want to create a dictionary of dictionaries to store all the co-occurrences of nouns and verbs/adjectives in each review, e.g.

'Very professional operation. Room is very clean and comfortable.'

`{'room': {'is': 1, 'clean': 1, 'comfortable': 1}`

Using the following code:

```
def count_co_occurences(reviews):
    # Iterate on each review and count
    occurences_per_review = {
        f"review_{i+1}": {
            noun: dict(Counter(review.lower().split(" ")))
            for noun in nouns
            if noun in review.lower()
        }
        for i, review in enumerate(reviews)
    }
    # Remove verb_adj not found in main list
    opr = deepcopy(occurences_per_review)
    for review, occurences in opr.items():
        for noun, counts in occurences.items():
            for verb_adj in counts.keys():
                if verb_adj not in verbs_adj:
                    del occurences_per_review[review][noun][verb_adj]
                    
    return occurences_per_review

pprint(count_co_occurences(data["reviews"]))
```

Works for when the lists and the number of reviews are small, but my notebook crashes when this function is used on large lists/large no. of reviews. How can I modify the code in order to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to use a couple of libraries to make your life easier. In this example I'm using nltk and collections, apart from pandas of course:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from collections import Counter

data = {'reviews':['Very professional operation. Room is very clean and comfortable',
                    'Daniel is the most amazing host! His place is extremely clean, and he provides everything you could possibly want (comfy bed, guidebooks & maps, mini-fridge, towels, even toiletries). He is extremely friendly and helpful.',
                    'The room is very quiet, and well decorated, very clean.',
                    'He provides the room with towels, tea, coffee and a wardrobe.',
                    'Daniel is a great host. Always recomendable.',
                    'My friend and I were very satisfied with our stay in his apartment.']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

nouns = ['place','Amsterdam','apartment','location','host','stay','city','room','everything','time','house',
         'area','home','’','center','restaurants','centre','Great','tram','très','minutes','walk','space','neighborhood',
         'à','station','bed','experience','hosts','Thank','bien']

verbs_adj = ['was','is','great','nice','had','clean','were','recommend','stay','are','good','perfect','comfortable',
             'have','easy','be','quiet','helpful','get','beautiful',"'s",'has','est','located','un','amazing','wonderful',]

def buildict(x):
    occurdict={}
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(x)
    tokenslower = list(map(str.lower, tokens)) 
    allnouns=[word for word in tokenslower if word in nouns]
    allverbs_adj=Counter(word for word in tokenslower if word in verbs_adj)
    for noun in allnouns:
        occurdict[noun]=dict(allverbs_adj)
    return occurdict

df['words']=df['reviews'].apply(lambda x: buildict(x))
```

output:

```
0   Very professional operation. Room is very clea...   {'room': {'is': 1, 'clean': 1, 'comfortable': 1}}
1   Daniel is the most amazing host! His place is ...   {'host': {'is': 3, 'amazing': 1, 'clean': 1, '...
2   The room is very quiet, and well decorated, ve...   {'room': {'is': 1, 'quiet': 1, 'clean': 1}}
3   He provides the room with towels, tea, coffee ...   {'room': {}}
4   Daniel is a great host. Always recomendable.    {'host': {'is': 1, 'great': 1}}
5   My friend and I were very satisfied with our s...   {'stay': {'were': 1, 'stay': 1}, 'apartment': ...
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Is it also possible to turn the dict of dicts into a dataframe? So each row would be all the nouns and each column would be the verbs/adjectives

Comment: Yes, it is possible, it would be something like dfdict=pd.DataFrame(occurdict).transpose() where occurdict is what the function buildict is returning (a dict of dicts)

Comment: I've attempted your solution and similar code but they all output just 1 row and a column for every dictionary value, I'm not sure why this is happening. But thank you for your help!